# Mover un input range desde otro objeto

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Me interesa poder mover el range desde el span sin tener que hacer click directamente en el.

Obviamente el range se movera dejando el click sostenido, normal, como si lo estuviera haciendo directamente en el range **¿Cómo lo puedo lograr?**

```css
body{
height: 100vh;
margin: 0;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: space-between;
}
input{
width: 100%;
}
span{
color: #fff;
padding: 10px;
background-color: green;
text-align: center;
cursor:  context-menu;
}
```

```html
<input type="range">

<span>Click aquí para mover el range</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asigna un "event listener" a tu "span" que modifique el atributo "value" de tu "input".

Ejemplo:

```js
var span = document.querySelector('span');
var input = document.querySelector('input');
span.addEventListener('click',function(){
  if(input.value > 20){
    input.value = input.value  - 10
  } else {
    input.value = 90
  }
});
```

```css
body{
height: 100vh;
margin: 0;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: space-between;
}
input{
width: 100%;
}
span{
color: #fff;
padding: 10px;
background-color: green;
text-align: center;
cursor:  context-menu;
}
```

```html
<input type="range">

<span>Click aquí para mover el range</span>
```

Referencias

- https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/input
- https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector
- https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener